# `require': cannot load such file -- debugger (LoadError) - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
/home/si/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- debugger (LoadError)
from /home/si/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/si/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I type rspec from the folder where lib and spec are present to get this error. I tried searching other links to no avail. Basically, I need to run autotest but it shows the "require could not load file" error.

What is the solution?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Use [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) for Ruby 2+. You'll have to install it using `gem install byebug`.

Comment: How to debug after that?

Comment: Read the documentation? Using a debugger is a good skill, and should be a well-used tool in your tool chest.

Comment: Oh! I'm a newbie here to ruby, rspec and autotest. 
Kind of baffled by the problem right now.

Comment: Is it a ruby version issue? 
gem list
rspec (3.3.0)
rspec-autotest (1.0.0)
rspec-core (3.3.2)
rspec-expectations (3.3.1)
rspec-mocks (3.3.2)
rspec-support (3.3.0)

Ruby is 2.2.1